# extracting segments from a file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that I need to extract segments from based on a character range given in another file. I would like to do it using an awk command.

File one would look like this ( a single line):

```
AATTGTGAAGGTAGATGGCTCGCTCCGCGGCGGGGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGGGCTCGCTATATAGAGATATATGCGCGCGGCGCGCGGCGCGCGCGGCGCGCGCGTATATATATAGGCGCGCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

The second file would look like follows:

```
5 10
13 20
22 24
```

and the output would be:

```
GTGAAG
AGATGGCT
GCT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one-liner will solve your problem:

`awk 'BEGIN{getline sequence < "first_file"} {print substr(sequence, $1, $2 - $1 + 1) }' second_file`

**Explanation:** This script reads string `sequence` from file named `first_file`(adjust it to the actual file name) using `getline` function. Then for each line of second file(which contains ranges for processing) it extracts necessary substring using `substr` function. `substr` accepts three parameters: string(`sequence`), position(`$1`), and length(`$2 - $1 + 1`).

Answer (score 1):

*Nya* gave you the `awk` solution, here's one based on `coreutils`.

**string**

```
AATTGTGAAGGTAGATGGCTCGCTCCGCGGCGGGGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGGGCTCGCTATATAGAGATATATGCGCGCGGCGCGCGGCGCGCGCGGCGCGCGCGTATATATATAGGCGCGCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

**offlen**

```
5 10
13 20
22 24
```

You can get the output you want with:

```bash
while read off len; do cut -c${off}-${len} string; done < offlen
```

Output:

```
GTGAAG
AGATGGCT
GCT
```